# How to select values by groups, using select sum()?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I need to select values by groups (from 0 to 10, from 10 to 50, more than 50).

```
user_id     amount
  1           20
  1           40
  2           5
  3           30
  3           1
```

Why this query doesn't work correctly?

```
select (select sum(amount)),
case 
when (select sum(amount))<10 then '0-10' 
when (select sum(amount))>=10 and (select sum(amount))<50 then '10-20' 
else '>50' end as total_amount, count(distinct user_id) 
from table
group by
case 
when (select sum(amount))<10 then '0-10' 
when (select sum(amount))>=10 and (select sum(amount))<50 then '10-20' 
else '>50' end as total_amount, count(distinct user_id);



 output
diapason number_of_users
0-10      1
10-50     1
>50       1
```

Give me hint plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has a number of issues, but primarily it will not work because you need to do the sum by user prior to the sorting into ranges. Try this instead:

```
SELECT CASE  
         WHEN amount BETWEEN  0 AND  9 THEN ' 0-10'
         WHEN amount BETWEEN 10 AND 50 THEN '10-50'
         ELSE '>50' END AS diapason,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_users
FROM (SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount 
      FROM payments 
      GROUP BY user_id) p
GROUP BY diapason;
```

Output

```
diapason    number_of_users
0-10        1
10-50       1
>50         1
```

Comment: can U tell what should I change in your query, to avoid  NULL?

Comment: Where are you seeing `NULL`?

Comment: here is no Null, but not in my real table .

Comment: Are there `NULL` values in the table, or in the output of the query? Or both?

Comment: may be I should to use Ifnull() ?

Comment: If you are seeing `NULL` in the `number_of_users` column, then yes, change `COUNT(*)` to `IFNULL(COUNT(*),0)`

Comment: what should I change in your query to set date interval? For example 12.04-18.04.2018?

Comment: The table data that you posted doesn't have any dates so there's no way to set a date interval...

Comment: I have query SELECT t.diapason, ifnull(COUNT(*),0) AS 'number_of_users'
FROM (SELECT CASE  
when amount<200 then '-200'
when amount>=200 then '200 +' END AS diapason
      FROM (SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount 
            FROM payments inner join activity on payments.user_id=activity.user_id and activity.login_time =payments.payment_time 
and activity.login_time between '2018-04-12' and'2018-04-18'
            GROUP BY payments.user_id) p) t
GROUP BY t.diapason
ORDER BY number_of_users desc;



It works incotect with date interval. Whats is wrong?

Comment: Hi Yelysei, your query seems reasonable. Without seeing the tables and some sample data it's really hard to guess what might be wrong. I think you should ask another question, include the query and some sample data from each table.

Comment: all is the same. I only want to restrict the task, if very amount has a date. Where should I write aditional restriction, for example "between '2018-04-12' and'2018-04-18' "?

Comment: can you look my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187595/how-to-add-a-few-restrictios-to-a-query
It is on basis of your query

Answer (score 0):

Try below way

```
    select 
    sum(case when amount <10 then 1 else 0 end) as "0-10",
    sum(case when amount >=10 and amount <50 then 1 else 0 end) as "0-50" ,       sum(case when amount>50 then 1 else 0 end) as ">50"   
    from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, writting a subquery get `SUM` of amount by each `user_id`, then do `CASE WHEN`, you don't need `select sum(amount)` in `CASE WHEN`.

```
CREATE TABLE t(
   user_id int,
   amount int
);


 insert into t values(1,20);
 insert into t values(1,40);
 insert into t values(2,5);
 insert into t values(3,30);
 insert into t values(3,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
    case 
        when t1.total<10 then '0-10' 
        when t1.total>=10 and t1.total<50 then '10-50' 
        else '>50' end as diapason, 
    count(distinct user_id) number_of_users
from (
  SELECT user_id,SUM(amount) total
  FROM table
  GROUP BY user_id
) t1
group by 
    case 
        when t1.total<10 then '0-10' 
        when t1.total>=10 and t1.total<50 then '10-50' 
    else '>50' end
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52c6ea/4/0)**:

```
| diapason | number_of_users |
|----------|-----------------|
|     0-10 |               1 |
|    10-50 |               1 |
|      >50 |               1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect:

```
select case 
    when amount<10 then '0-10' 
    when  samount>=10 and amount<50 then '10-20' 
    else '>50' end as total_amount, count(distinct user_id) 
    from table
    group by
    case 
    when amount<10 then '0-10' 
    when  samount>=10 and amount<50 then '10-20' 
    else '>50' end
```