# How to add a few restrictios to a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have difficulty with syntax...

This is my query:

```
SELECT t.diapason,
       Count(*) AS 'number_of_users'
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN amount < 200 THEN '0-200'
                 WHEN amount >= 200 THEN '200 +'
               end AS diapason
        FROM   (SELECT Sum(amount) AS amount
                FROM   payments) p) t
GROUP  BY t.diapason
ORDER  BY number_of_users DESC;
```

But now I need to select only users which had activity.login_time between '2018-01-01' and'2018-01-12'.

So, I think I should use INNER JOIN and set period of time. Bu how?

My tables:

```
activity
user_id    login_time
1          01.01.2018
2          01.01.2018
3          03.01.2018
4          30.02.2018

payments
user_id    amount   payment_time
1          50       10.12.2017
1          200      09.12.2017
2          40        08.08.2017
```

what should I change in my query to add activity.login_time?

Output for period 01.01.2018-12.01.2018

```
diapason     number_of_users
0-200          2
200+           1
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Note that 12 comes after 10.

Comment: Are the dates in the table actually in the format `01.01.2018` or is that after conversion for output?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can get your expected result since there are only two distinct user_ids in the payments table? Also the result seems to be independent of the `payment_time` is that correct?

Comment: The answer I was looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191633/how-it-is-better-to-join-a-few-tables-including-subqueries-in-one-query/

Comment: @Nick, I have got the answer I needed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191633/how-it-is-better-to-join-a-few-tables-including-subqueries-in-one-query/).

Comment: @Nick, If it possible, give me hint how should change question to display total result in the same query?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as this. You had 3 users (user_id=1,2,3) login in the period 01.01.2018-12.01.2018. Of those users, user_id 1 made 2 payments totalling 250, user_id 2 made 1 payment of 40, and user_id 3 made 0 payments so their total is 0. Hence there are 2 values in the range `0-200`, and 1 in the range `200 +`. If that is the correct understanding, this query will give you the desired results:

```
SELECT CASE  
         WHEN amount < 200 THEN '0-200'
         WHEN amount >= 200 THEN '200 +'
       END AS diapason,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_users
FROM (SELECT a.user_id, COALESCE(SUM(p.amount), 0) AS amount
      FROM activity a
      LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.user_id = a.user_id
      WHERE a.login_time BETWEEN '01.01.2018' AND '12.01.2018'
      GROUP BY a.user_id) p
GROUP BY diapason;
```

Output:

```
diapason    number_of_users
0-200       2
200 +       1
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28a3cf/8)

**Update**

To add another row with the total `number_of_users`, just add `WITH ROLLUP` to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT CASE  
         WHEN amount < 200 THEN '0-200'
         WHEN amount >= 200 THEN '200 +'
       END AS diapason,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_users
FROM (SELECT a.user_id, COALESCE(SUM(p.amount), 0) AS amount
      FROM activity a
      LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.user_id = a.user_id
      WHERE a.login_time BETWEEN '01.01.2018' AND '12.01.2018'
      GROUP BY a.user_id) p
GROUP BY diapason WITH ROLLUP
```

Output:

```
diapason    number_of_users
0-200       2
200 +       1
(null)      3
```

In your application framework you can use the fact that the `diapason` value is `NULL` to output something like `Total` instead.

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28a3cf/11)

You can also do the same in MySQL (see this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28a3cf/13)) by wrapping this query up as a subquery and using a `COALESCE` on the `diapason` column. In that case the output would be:

```
diapason    number_of_users
0-200       2
200 +       1
Total       3
```

Comment: thanks, but how to display total (in this case = 3) too in ths query?

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков I've edited my answer to show how to create a summary row

Comment: @Nick thanks! Didn't know about `WITH ROLLUP` but that can be very useful!

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes - much easier than doing it yourself! :)

Answer (score 0):

You add `WHERE` clause to filter.

```
SELECT t.diapason,
       COUNT(*) AS 'number_of_users'
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN amount < 200 THEN '0-200'
            WHEN amount >= 200 THEN '200 +'
        END AS diapason
    FROM   (
        SELECT payments.user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
        FROM   payments
        INNER JOIN activity ON payments.user_id = activity.user_idAND activity.login_time = payments.payment_time
        WHERE activity.login_time BETWEEN '2018-01-10' AND '2018-01-12'
        GROUP  BY payments.user_id
    ) p
) t
GROUP  BY t.diapason
ORDER  BY number_of_users DESC;
```

Comment: thanks , but doesn't work. May be there's a mistake?

Comment: I updated a little bit qoustion. I don't know in which part of the query I should use Inner Join. I tried in different parts, but it gives different result....

Comment: may be I don't understand "activity.login_time = payments.payment_time".Why?

Comment: @YelyseiGorkov Updating your question by telling us what you're trying to achieve.  We can't help you you post a broken query without telling us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @YelyseiGorkov`activity.login_time = payments.payment_time` was in your original query.  I don't know why.