# How it is better to join a few tables (including subqueries) in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

How it is better to join a few tables (including suqueries) in one query?

For example, I've got 2 tables: activity (user_id, login_time) and payments (user_id, payment_time, amount). Both tables conclude duplicate id's.

The task is to select unique user_id, which ever payed, with login_time from 05.04.12 until 10.04.12. Then range the by group accotding of total amount.

My query is:

```
SELECT t.diapason, COUNT(*) AS 'number_of_users'
FROM (SELECT CASE  
    when amount<100 then '0-100' 
    when amount>=100 then '100 +' END AS diapason
    FROM 
        (SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount 
        FROM payments GROUP BY payments.user_id) p) t
  GROUP BY t.diapason
  ORDER BY number_of_users desc;
```

I dont know where should I use 'inner join a....between '2012-04-05' and'2012-04-10''

Please help, thanks!

DATA SAMPLE

```
activity
user_id    login_time
1          05.04.2012
2          05.04.2012
3          06.04.2012
4          30.05.2012

payments
user_id    amount   payment_time
1          50       10.12.2011
1          20        09.12.2011
2          400        08.08.2011

Output for period 05.04.2012-10.04.2012

diapason     number_of_users
0-100          2
100+           1
```

Comment: some sample data and expected output would help!

Comment: Isn't this the same question as you posted earlier today???  Again no one can help you without some more info.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a few restrictios to a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187595/how-to-add-a-few-restrictios-to-a-query)

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of the same question that you asked earlier. Please go back and edit the original question if you want to change it, rather than posting a new one. Otherwise, you will create a lot of confusion.

Comment: @BobRodes, I did'n found an anwer ((

Comment: You're not going to get one by reposting the question. Also, you have an answer on your original question, provided two hours ago.

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya, I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this gets you what you're looking for (one of many ways):

```
SELECT t.diapason, COUNT(*) AS 'number_of_users'
FROM (SELECT CASE  
    when amount<100 then '0-100' 
    when amount>=100 then '100 +' END AS diapason
    FROM 
        (SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount 
        FROM payments 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM activity where login_time between '2012-04-05' and '2012-04-12') AS a ON payments.user_id = a.user_id
        GROUP BY payments.user_id) AS P
      ) t
GROUP BY t.diapason
  ORDER BY number_of_users desc
;
```

Comment: Probably the date, I wasn't able to test in mySQL specifically.  probably need to modify the between condition to something like scaisEdge has: e.g. BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2012-05-04', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2012-10-04', '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Also is login time an actual date? or is it a time? (MM.DD.YYYY or HH.MI.SSSS)  The column type is an important detail for the date/time conversions

Comment: I use in this case simple 'between '2012-04-01' and '2012-04-100'. It works. May be you have goy mistake in syntax (before INNER JOIN) or it is needed? 
'

Comment: Done, was missing the 'AS'

Comment: what should I change to add total result below? Answer, plz